# Syntax - what does square brackets around a variable declaration mean

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, declaration

Take the following line of code

```
const [component] = router.getMatchedComponents({ ...to })
```

Could anyone advise what the square brackets around component means here? I have tried to google this but struggling to find an answer

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's called [**Destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it's used to unpack the values of an `array` and assign them to new variables.

So here in your code:

```
const [component] = router.getMatchedComponents({ ...to })
```

You are assigning to the `component` variable the first element held in the `array` that will be returned by `router.getMatchedComponents({...to})`, where `to` is an array-like structure turned into `object` using the spread operation.

Comment: Thanks! so this would mean in the example I posted its essentially doing an array shift on the array returned by router.getMatchedComponents({ ...to }) and setting component to this right?

Comment: @Neil Yes, kind of. but it's assigning it to a new variable.